# UIViewController access subviews before viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a subclass of UIViewController and I define a variable like this:

```
 public class CustomController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider:UISlider!

     public var showSlider = false {
        didSet {       
          slider.isHidden = !showSlider
        }
      }
      ...
      ...
  }
```

And now if I instantiate my custom view controller like this:

```
  let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomController") as! CustomController

  controller.showSlider = true
```

The problem is the second line may be called even before viewDidLoad or IBOutlets are even set. How to deal with a situation like this?

Comment: View is loaded at that point, the issue is something else.

Comment: No it's not loaded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code will crash as you access the outlet before presentation , so You need `loadViewIfNeeded`

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomController") as! Cust   omController 
controller.loadViewIfNeeded()
controller.showSlider = true
```

Comment: the program doesn't crash but doesn't work either...slider remains hidden for strange reasons.

Comment: Ok the problem seems to be autolayout constraints. In XCode 11, sometimes everything in "Add New Constraints" is grayed out when setting leading/trailing constraints. Any idea why constraints menu is grayed out?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you call `showSlider = true` in controller's `viewDidLoad` method?

Like this:

```swift
public class CustomController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var slider:UISlider!

    public var showSlider = false {
        didSet {       
            slider.isHidden = !showSlider
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showSlider = true
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is it is customizable. Can be turned off any time. We can not set it to true always.